# Stop screen after btdownloadcurses download done

Tags: php, python

I am using the following at my php code

```
$shell_cmd = 'sudo screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses "'.$selected_torrent.'" --display_interval 20 --saveas "'. $file_folder . $selected_filename.'"';
$commandRUN = '/usr/bin/nohup ' . $shell_cmd . ' >/dev/null 2>&1 &';
shell_exec($shell_cmd);
```

The purpose is to save the bit torrent to my server, and to run as screen, its work fine and work in background.

The issue now is how do I auto stop my screen when my btdownloadcurses download complete, how do we monitor the progress or so and terminate screen, I thought of using python script to achieve this .

Comment: Is it a homemade script? You can just get the progression of the download (It depends of your script) and when it's finished, execute `screen -X quit`

Comment: I am using a cli btdownloadcurses , bit tornado for cli linux